# Wildfly 10 or higher - Logging - Is it possible to append a session value to every single log message?

Tags: logging, wildfly

In wildfly, is it possible to append a value that's in the session to every single log message? We have a UUID in the session wondering if there is a way to include that in every single log message without having to update every single log statement in code.

**Current logs:**

```
2020-02-20 13:34:54,912 INFO  [com.example.app.Main] User1 Completed payment.
```

**Expected logs:** (Appending UUID to the beginning of the log)

```
2020-02-20 13:34:54,912 INFO  [com.example.app.Main] [27b2d9d2-540c-11ea-8d77-2e728ce88125] User1 Completed payment.
```

Comment: What logging framework/facade do you use? You should able to use MDC to accomplish this if your facade supports it.

Comment: Ah I see. We are using log4J. Can you point me to an article or documentation that has more information on MDC?

Comment: I found this article - https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/. Looks like that exactly what I want. Thanks!